# How to print what I think is an object?

Tags: python, generator

```
test = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

def xuniqueCombinations(items, n):
    if n==0: yield []
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(items)-n+1):
            for cc in xuniqueCombinations(items[i+1:],n-1):
                yield [items[i]]+cc

x = xuniqueCombinations(test, 3)
print x
```

outputs

```
"generator object xuniqueCombinations at 0x020EBFA8"
```

I want to see all the combinations that it found. How can i do that?

Comment: two things: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html and http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator

Answer (score 17, accepted):

leoluk is right, you need to iterate over it. But here's the correct syntax:

```
combos = xuniqueCombinations(test, 3)
for x in combos:
    print x
```

Alternatively, you can convert it to a list first:

```
combos = list(xuniqueCombinations(test, 3))
print combos
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a generator object. Access it by iterating over it:

```
for x in xuniqueCombinations:
    print x
```

Comment: for x in xuniqueCombinations:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: @Alex You need to call the function: `for x in xuniqueCombinations(test, 3)`. Alternatively just do `print list(xuniqueCombinations(test, 3))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = list(xuniqueCombinations(test, 3))
print x
```

convert your generator to list, and print......

Comment: Don't like this answer without at least a warning about the memory implications.

Comment: ohh ok, but if someone executes loop over generator object for printing without converting it to list, he can not execute loop over it again without calling that function again as iterator will be exhausted ....

Answer (score -3):

It might be handy to look at the pprint module: http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html if you're running python 2.7 or more:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(x)
```

Comment: pprint(x)
<generator object xuniqueCombinations at 0x020EBFA8>

that is no different...